# Java Cannot Find Runtime Environment Only for Other People

Tags: java, runtime, environment

I made a game in Eclipse, exported it as a jar, and used Jar2Exe to turn it to an executable. I can run the game fine, but when anyone I send it to tries to run it, they get "Java Cannot Find Runtime Environment".

The people that tested it had the same version of java I have (1.8), and they do have a JRE on their computer.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Perhaps you could ask them to run it from the command line to see if you can get a more detailed error

Comment: Are you sure they have the JRE installed? Not just the JDK? Anyway, maybe you should check out the documentation on how it finds the JRE: [Jar2exe.com - Find JRE Itself](http://www.jar2exe.com/createdexe/intro/findjre). Pay special attention to the following part: **32 bits of generated exe can run with 32 bits of JRE only. 64 bits of generated exe can run with 64 bits of JRE only.**

Comment: Lets follow a binary search approach to debugging. And here the middle point is does the jar work? I.e. java -jar yourgame.jar runs fine on their system or not? If it does not then java runtime is missing or java home is not set on their systems, else jar2exe has messed up. Try this and then come back and we will try further to find the issue.

Comment: When I ran the command in my console, it said there is no main manifest attribute in the jar. When someone else ran the command, it says picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024M, and there is no main manifest attribute. After he did java -version, it said he had java version 1.8.0, and the same version of Java SE Runtime Environment.  Oh and whenever I create the exe with jar2exe, it has an options that says: create 64 bit executable, and if I dont check it, then I get the no Java Runtime Environment. So I keep check checked. Maybe I leave it unchecked for other people? @faizan

Comment: @joey942 : When you create the jar from ide remember to specify the main class. Which IDE/build tool are you using?

Comment: Extract the jar file and check the manifest folder -> manifest.mf, tell if you see a main-class attribute. Or paste the contents of manifest here

Comment: @faizan I am using Eclipse.  In the manifest folder, there is only manifest.mf.

Comment: Paste the contents of manifest.mf here, It should have a line like: Main-Class: io.faizan.Main , if does not then there is an issue. Also that class should be in the packed jar. If it is possible then can you share the github source repo for your project so that I can try to build it?